# Mutable Map Collection in Scala can NOT update a single element

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections

I have the following problem.

```
val graph = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, Int]() ++= (0 until 10).map(i => (i, i + 1)).toMap

graph(graph.size - 1) = 20   // BOOOM!!!

val graphSize = 9
graph(graphSize) = 20     //BOOM!!!

graph(9) = 20    //Works Fine!
```

Whenever i try to update a single element in a Mutable Map with a variable it explodes!!!

```
Error:(45, 120) not found: value graph
inst$A$A.`get$$instance_2$$graph(graph.size - 1)`;
println("graph(graph.size - 1): " + {val $$temp$$ = inst$A$A.graph(graph.size      - 1) ;
MacroPrinter.printDefInfo($$temp$$).replace("inst$A$A.", "") + " = " + ( print$$$Worksheet$$$Array$$$($$temp$$) ).stripPrefix("A$A65$A$A65$")})
                                                                                                                  ^
```

I have no idea why does this happen. Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean "BOOM"? I just ran it in the REPL and it worked fine.

Comment: Error:(26, 120) not found: value graph
inst$A$A.`get$$instance_0$$graph(graph.size - 1)`; println("graph(graph.size - 1): " + {val $$temp$$ = inst$A$A.graph(graph.size - 1) ; MacroPrinter.printDefInfo($$temp$$).replace("inst$A$A.", "") + " = " + ( print$$$Worksheet$$$Array$$$($$temp$$) ).stripPrefix("A$A48$A$A48$")})
                                                                                                                      ^

Comment: the error message basically says there is no such thing as graph. Do you have other things in between (e.g. the usage of graph not being in the same scope as graph definition)?. Just putting these two lines into the REPL works fine.

Comment: @AssafMendelson No I don't have anything between. I have no idea why this happens to me. I am trying to figure it out from yesterday but i still have no answer. :(((

Comment: try to simplify everything. The code as is works in the REPL (and I just put it in an existing project and it works too).

Comment: @AssafMendelson I edited my initial Post. For some strange reason, it works only if i put graph(9) =  20. But If i put a variable it gives me the above error! very frustrating.. :(((

Answer (score 0):

Alright. After many runs back and forth i figured that only update() method does the work! Don't know why yet.
So Updates are only done by:

```
graph.update(key, value)
```

At least in my machine...